# How to obtain the autocorrelation of an unevenly sampled time series (containing longer gaps)?

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, correlation, time-series, pattern-recognition

Problem: 
Obtain the autocorrelation of unevenly(!) sampled time series.

Data (Time series) description:
~$10^6$ unevenly sampled time series, each containing ~$10^4$ data points at irregular intervals.

Distribution of the interval (gap) length:

- 12 seconds   :   most common (minimum)
- 12-18 hours  :   very common
- 1-5 days     :   occasionally
- 1 week - 3 months : rare

The data is periodic (but the amplitudes are not constant) with periods from 1 hour - 100 days and thus on the same order as many of the gaps.
The shape of the signals is not always sinusoidal.

Standard approaches (that do not work):

- Lamb-Scargle Fourier Transform: 
  This method does not work since the signals are not sinusoidal, but can   contain sharp peaks etc.
- (Linear) interpolation (then use standard time series analysis): 
  This method does not work because the gaps are too large and too common, since whole oscillations are missing.
- Gaussian process regression/ Kernel methods:
  They can be made to work  - however they are unfortunately much too slow to compute the autocorrelation of all ~$10^6$ time series.

EDIT:
I am at this moment unable to publish any sample data sets publicly.